# how to mimic "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"?

Tags: c#, api

for testing purposes, I would like to mimic the following error:
"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

how can I do that using c#?

Comment: This is Winsock error `WSAECONNREFUSED`, error 10061, so `throw new SocketException(10061)` will do it, if you don't actually want to attempt a physical connection to a port that's not open (which would also be easy to do, by just using `localhost` and any port not likely to be open, like `finger` port 79).